# Storing reference of a function in typed array

Tags: node.js

I have a huge list of functions and i need to store them to a typed array.

list for 10 millions function :

```
var size = 10000000 * 4;
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer( size);
var int32View = new Int32Array(buffer);

//How to store a function address in the list?
int32View[0]= addressof(myfunc);

//How to retrieve a function from the list?
myfunc = int32View[0] as function;
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate more on _why_ do you need to use a typed array for that? ArrayBuffer's purpose is a bit different actually. And how big is that huge list of functions, couldn't it be trimmed/reorganized?

Comment: Node spends more than 1 second storing and retrieving 10 millions int value in a normal list but it took only 40 milliseconds via typed list. Function call in node is very fast but working with list is slower than c# or native languages. It can be very useful when you need data as operation.

Comment: The use case you described - bulk insert, bulk read of _immutable_ data - is indeed where ArrayBuffer/TypedArray infrastructure shines. But it's not relevant to function ops.

Comment: Also, can't help wondering what's the case for using 10 million functions. )

Comment: You're right, There must be a better solution. Thank you